# SQL Server stored procedure for updating a table in SQL Server 2012 with incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have the below stored procedure, and I am getting this error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '01'

I have other stored procedures which begin with '01,' and they work ok. I'm not sure where the incorrect syntax is.

Thanks for any leads.

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[01_news_test]   
(
     [interestid] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
     [username]   [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
     [approval]   [BIT] NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_news_test] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([interestid] DESC)
                     WITH (pad_index = OFF, statistics_norecompute = OFF, 
                           ignore_dup_key = OFF, allow_row_locks = on, 
                           allow_page_locks = on, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the code for the stored procedure (below):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[01_cms_news_mgr_bull_appr_update]
    @InterestID INT,
    @Approval BIT
AS
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT @sql = ' UPDATE [01_news_test] ' +
              ' SET ' +
              ' Approval = @Approval ' +
              ' WHERE ' 

    IF @InterestID IS NOT NULL 
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' InterestID = @InterestID'

    SELECT @sql = @sql + '; '

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@InterestID INT, @Approval BIT', InterestID, Approval
```

And, here is the code upon execution of the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @return_value INT

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[01_cms_news_mgr_bull_appr_update]
               @InterestID = 1,         
               @Approval = 0

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Finally, the resulting error msg:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '01'

Update: adding a bracket around the table name fixed the 'incorrect syntax error,' although I now am getting an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to int

Comment: In your stored procedure, the @sql string: try putting brackets around the table name so it'll read `UPDATE [01_news_test]`

Comment: missing comma after first parameter?

Comment: Thanks.  I added the bracket, and that took care of the syntax error.  Now I am getting "error converting data type nvarchar to int."  I had typed a numeric zero into the ssms interface input, like in my example above.

Comment: there is no reason to use dynamic sql in this stored procedure, that should take care of most of the problems

Comment: I do not understand why you are using dynamic query here..it's a simple update statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be in the final line of my code, with the addition of '@' prepending the final 2 variables.

I've posted the solution below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[01_cms_news_mgr_bull_appr_update]
    @InterestID INT,
    @Approval BIT AS
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT @sql = ' UPDATE [01_news_test] ' +
              ' SET ' +
              ' Approval = @Approval ' +
              ' WHERE ' 

    IF @InterestID IS NOT NULL 
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' InterestID = @InterestID'

    SELECT @sql = @sql + '; '

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@InterestID INT, @Approval BIT', @InterestID, @Approval
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 01_cms_new_mgr_bull_appr_update stored proc doesn't explicitly return a value, so, it is probably returning either 0 or -1, indicating the proc completed or failed for some reason.

Then, your statement:

```
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Would not be returning a column named [Return Value] with a value of @return_value.  It would probably be trying to assign the @return_value (int) to the const char string 'Return Value'.  You could try:

```
SELECT @return_value AS return_value
GO
```

OR

```
SELECT 'Return Value = ' + @return_value AS return_string
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented, avoid any dynamic build of query since no structural component such as tables or columns needs to be dynamically modified. Parameters can be used directly in declared SQL statements.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[01_cms_news_mgr_bull_appr_update]
    @InterestID INT,
    @Approval BIT
AS

BEGIN
    UPDATE [01_news_test] 
    SET Approval = @Approval
    WHERE InterestID = @InterestID
END
```